# Proper way of serving images with SSG in Next.js

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, google-cloud-storage, static-site-generation

What's a proper way of serving images when using SSG?

Currently, the images are retreived using a custom image loader.
This loader creates the URL to my (locally hosted) CMS' api, which allows real-time image optimization using `GET` parameters.

The issue here is that when hosting my static files (coming from  `next build && next export`) on Github Pages, it doesn't have access to my local CMS' api anymore, causing `404`'s for all images.

As a solution, I made the CMS store all it's files on Google Cloud Storage, but GCS doesn't seem to support real-time image optimization so it's loading full resolutions.

Is this even the right solution? If it is, which storage providers do support real-time image optimization?